# Afnetworking 3.0: How do I receive responses to multiple requests in the correct order?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I have an AFNetwork GET request like this.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

This works well accept for the fact when I have to send multiple requests. Sometimes I will get second response before the first response which means I get the responses in a incorrect order.

I've tried using this

```
 manager.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

However, I still received the responses in the wrong order. I am not sure what to do or what to look for in regards to this. Seems like most of the stack overflow questions regarding this situation involves an older afnetworking. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Edit: The importance of the order is I need to display certain text in a tableview in a specific order. If request 2 response comes in first, the table view text won't be in the correct order.

Comment: what importance does the order hold for you? do you just need to tie the response to the request, or the order has some real meaning? what is that meaning? what's the data and how are you using it?

Comment: I need to display certain text in a table view in a certain order. I've edited by question.

Comment: You can do in the `success` block call another `GET:` to respect the order. You can also in the `success` block retrieve the URL to know which one was called, keep them, and display them accordingly.